# enable/disable trigger via code C#

Tags: c#, sql, triggers

Is there any way to enable or disable a SQL SERVER trigger programmatically in C#, or do I have to modify the trigger itself to control whether or not my code invokes it?

Comment: Maybe you mean an event?

Comment: oh, really sorry, the trigger that I mentionated is a SQL TRIGGER.

Comment: @jaspion: you can edit your question to include any details that you may have forgotten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute a [DISABLE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx) via a [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)