# Enabling Disabling Sqlserver Trigger on button Click

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it possible to enable or disable sqlserver triggers from C# on Button Click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           try
                {
                    string connectionString = @"Data Source=ABC-SERVER;Initial Catalog=TESTCO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password";
                    using (SqlConnection conn =
                        new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand("DISABLE TRIGGER [dbo].[MSETUP] ON [dbo].[parts] ", conn))
                        {
                             int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
          }
```

How can i get this to work from C# or any suggestions?

Comment: The login failed is a different issue than what you are asking.

Comment: The application can't log into SQL with that connection string.  After you've fixed that you should be able to do whatever you want.

Comment: @Seano666 so the code is good to update disable trigger? if the login error fixed?

Comment: Answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838062/enable-disable-trigger-via-code-c-sharp

Comment: I have to say the disabling a database trigger is a pretty good indication that there are some serious design issues.